# measure deceleration with html5

Tags: javascript, html

A Meteor client code needs to measure deceleration of a mobile phone while positioned vertically facing the user who happened to have the phone mounted inside a braking car.
Since the development environment is on a laptop and the `event.acceleration` may not be available all the times `event.accelerationIncludingGravity` is used instead.

How can this be done?

```js
if (window.DeviceMotionEvent) {
  window.addEventListener("devicemotion", handleMotionEvent, true);
}

function handleMotionEvent(event) {
  let y = event.accelerationIncludingGravity.y;
  let z = event.accelerationIncludingGravity.z;
  let a = Math.sqrt(y * y + z * z); //horizontal acceleration regardless of device beta angle
console.log(y + ' : ' + z);  // 0.5 : 9.85344
}
```

Do I expect to see a negative "z" value?
Why the 9.8 value is included in the "z" and not in the "y"?

Comment: from which device did you get those y-z values? in android mobile using chrome, i get most of 9.8 in "y"

Comment: Should this question include the Meteor.js tag?